# AWS S3 upload time limit to complete

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-nodejs

What is the time limit of an upload stream using upload api of amazon s3?
Does it have to be complete in a certain timeframe?

For context I'm using nodejs, [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#upload-property) is the function I'm referring to.

I'm assembling an archive and piping it to [Passthrough](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_passthrough) stream and sending via upload api, but assembling the archive might be time consuming (might be an hour or more even).

Would I get timeout exception?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no timeout, at least it's not a publicly known [quota](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/qfacts.html) but you need to account for other potential timeouts such as your server's configuration.  For example if you're running this from a Lambda you'd have a 15 minute timeout.

I would recommend uploading your archive as a [multipart upload](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/mpuoverview.html) where you initiate the upload, send it parts as pieces of your archive become available and then signal that it's complete.  S3 will handle concatenating all of the parts into a single object.

Comment: Thank you Brian for your answer, for a multipart upload we have to have a file ready at hand, right? It won't work with streams right?

Comment: For simplicity's sake I would write the parts to tmp storage locally and then upload each part as they are completed.  You could stream to S3 upload but you need to know the filesize of each part beforehand.  I'd need to see some code to give you a clearer idea.